# Having a issue casting a object from an ArrayCollection to an instance of my Custom Class

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I am using Flex 4 and for whatever reason I cannot get the following code to work which happens inside of a ListEvent handler for a dataGrid:

```
_tempRule = DataGrid(event.currentTarget).selectedItem as Rule;
```

Rule is a custom class, and the above code always returns null. The dataprovider for the datagrid is an ArrayCollection. If I try to wrap the above code to make it like the following:

```
DataGrid(event.currentTarget).selectedItem as Rule
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@e15a971 to com.mycompany.arcc.business.Rule
```

Now I know I have done this before with native Flex classes like Button, etc, but it my case it will not work.

Here is the Rule class:

```
    package com.mycompaany.arcc.business
{
    import flash.utils.describeType;

    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    [Bindable]
    public class Rule extends Object
    {
        public static const RANGE:String = "Range";
        public static const SINGLE:String = "Single";
        public static const LIST:String = "List";

        /*name of the rule*/
        private var _name:String;

        /*rule group, like a radio group, only 1 rule from a group can be selected*/
        private var _group:String;

        /*Description of the group for the rule*/
        private var _groupDescription:String;

        /*Description of the rule*/
        private var _description:String;

        /*arry of values for this rule, based on the control type*/
        private var _values:ArrayCollection;

        /*min num of values*/
        private var _numValues:int;

        /*type of control to build, if range, 2 inputs, single, 1 , list 1 or more*/
        private var _type:String;

        public function Rule(name:String=null, group:String=null, description:String=null, values:ArrayCollection=null, numValues:int=0, type:String=null)
        {
            super();
            _values = new ArrayCollection();

            this._name = name
            this._group = group;  
            this._description = description;
            if (values)
            {
                this._values = values;
            }
            this._numValues = numValues;  
            this._type = type;  
        }


    }
}
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: Can we see the code where you populate the ArrayCollection for the DataGrid?  It looks like you're not populating the ArrayCollection with the proper object type (hence the casting issue when accessing the datagrid's selected item), but it's hard to tell without a little more context.

Comment: I am binding the dataprovider to a presentation model public property. If I step through the selectedItem object in debugger I see it has all the properties of the Rule Class. I will see about updating with more code.

Comment: Ok, I think I have some more pertinent information. I actually have a spark list component that has an ArrayCollection of Rules. I am dragging the selecteditem from that List to the above mentioned Datagrid where I want to do some further processing on the object. Casting to my custom class works fine on the selected item in the list however. It looks like something is happening to the object when it is copied to the other arrayCollection.

Comment: @BrandonG, excellent -- making good progress :)  When you drag the item into the DataGrid, are you manually handling the drag drop method, and extracting the pertinent information from the dragged item and creating a new Rule which is added?  Or is Flex automatically handling the drag/drop for you?

Comment: I am letting Flex handle all the drag and drop functionality.

Comment: Try adding an event listener on your DataGrid to handle the "dragDrop" event -- add a trace statement and debug when the drop happens.  You'll be able to tell what's in the dragged item and what's being added to the data provider from there.  You might want to prevent the default action and simply extract whatever data you need from the dragged item and add a new Rule object to the DataGrid.

Comment: Well I found a different solution, http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dragdrop_4.html. If I put [RemoteClass] at the top of my class it preserves the type of my object and everything works normally. I am fairly certain your method will work as I have done something similar on a previous project.

Comment: @BrandonG, glad you found a solution :)  I wasn't aware of the [RemoteClass] tag fixing issues like this, but it sounds like a simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and easy solution was to add the [RemoteClass] metatag at the top my custom class.
I found this solution on Adobe's website, [livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/….](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dragdrop_4.html) It seems that using the native drag and drop capabilities between list-based components causes custom classes to lose their type during copying. Thanks to everyone for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

the errormessage is the result of an failed casting.
The better way is to use the cast like this,

```
Rule((event.currentTarget).selectedItem);
```

In this case, you will receive an exception, when the cast fails and not a null reference
BR
Frank

Comment: it seems this issue is due to the fact that I amc opying a custom class with the native drag and drop, and Flash loses the type during that process. However, you are correct, I would get an exception with your method. I detailed that in my post above. Thanks.